# Find a userA who has GenericAll rights over the userB using Active Directory Recon

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Say for example I have user Matt and I want to know if any other users have GenericAll rights on user Matt, What's the correct command for that

```
Get-DomainObjectAcl -Identity matt -ResolveGUIDs -Domain testlab.local
```

The above command doesnt return any info about other users rights on Matt unless I am misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ObjectAcl -SamAccountName joe.blane | ?{$_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq "GenericAll"}
```

then

```
Convert-SidToName <SID>
```